# Should I learn Express.js or Sails.js?

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js

I am learning node.js these days. I have gone through some nodeJS framework as well like expressJS and sailsJS but not able to decide which framework should I choose?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I suggest to use sails.js , as it has better MVC structure and If you take Sails.js, then you are still on Express. It also give you a base architecture and good start points for your projects.

Better go through this link and decide :
http://www.quora.com/Should-one-learn-Express-js-or-Sails-js

Comment: Koa is quite popular now. So I would suggest looking up Koa framework. If you are a RAILS developer then I suggest using SAILS due to familiarity

Answer (score 4):

You need to be at least familar with Express.js - it's like a standart now.

Answer (score 3):

I would also suggest you to use sails.js as Sails makes it easy to build custom, enterprise-grade Node.js apps.
Rest you can have a look on this:

http://vschart.com/compare/sails-js/vs/express-web-framework

Comment: Can you suggest me any good tutorial on sails? I didn't find good documentation on http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-sailsjs--net-35390

Comment: you can go through the above link , it will help you :)

Comment: rest I will suggest you to go through http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/ only as it is the main documentation for sails, you can see the refrence later if you go stuck somewhere in the main documentation

Comment: thanx for your help.