# Node MVC app with dynamodb ORM including associations

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js, amazon-dynamodb, vogels

I want to build a Node.js MVC app.
My data is stored in dynamoDB. I'm looking for a suitable framework for this.
I'm mainly debating between:

- Express.js (for the controllers) with vogels  as the ORM (for the
  models),
- Sails.js with the [dynamoDB adapter](https://github.com/gadelkareem/sails-dynamodb) .

I prefer to have associations support between models so that I'll not need to implement it myself in my code.
Can anybody advise what are the props and cons of both options? Can i do with the second option everything I can do in the first option but with less code? Any other recommendations?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32474970/should-i-learn-express-js-or-sails-js

Comment: Thanks for the links. I want to know specifically about the right ORM to use with DynamoDB, together with one of those frameworks.

Comment: Can anybody share experience with the sails dynamodb-adapter? Does it look/work like any other Sails app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, this is very opinion based question. So, I would just give my opinion. This does not mean one is far better than the other.

I have used Vogels for some use cases. I have found it very useful. Some of the advantages of Vogels are:-

1) **Parallel scans** - Helps to improve performance which developers would most likely come across at some point of the project especially if you are going to maintain millions of records in DynamoDB

2) Supports both global and local secondary indexes - Based on the query pattern, the application would most likely require index on tables. So this feature is very helpful

3) Data type and validation support using Joi ([Joi Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi))

4) Automatic addition of audit timestamp fields such as updatedAt, createdAt

5) Automatic key value generation in UUID format

6) **Chainable API** for query and scan operations - You can chain multiple filter conditions with limit option for pagination and sort the results as well

7) Load multiple models with in a single request (Batch get items feature)

8) Basic **streaming** api

9) Some good sample codes for many features which is very important for developers

Comment: Thanks for the answer very helpful, it's good to hear the opinion of experienced people.

Comment: Glad to help. Would you like to accept or upvote the answer?